# Tcolorbox as an item in list environment

Tags: tcolorbox

I have used `tcolorbox` as an item to highlight some content. It works fine in general.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textbullet}]\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.934\textwidth,colback={white},title={Title},colbacktitle={DarkGreen},coltitle=white,colframe={DarkGreen}]
         \parskip=5pt

          Some text
          \end{tcolorbox}
          }
    \item Some Item 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However, whenever I have to use another list environment or centered table/figure, the item dot is pushed inside the box. I want that item dot to remain outside of the box. Please tell me how to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textbullet}]\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.934\textwidth,colback={white},title={Title},colbacktitle={DarkGreen},coltitle=white,colframe={DarkGreen}]
         \parskip=5pt

          Some text
          \begin{enumerate}
               \item A
               \item B
          \end{enumerate}
          \end{tcolorbox}
          }
    \item Some Item 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start the paragraph before inserting the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textbullet}]
    \leavevmode %<--------------
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.934\textwidth,colback={white},title={Title},colbacktitle={DarkGreen},coltitle=white,colframe={DarkGreen}]
         \parskip=5pt

          Some text
          \begin{enumerate}
               \item A
               \item B
          \end{enumerate}
          \end{tcolorbox}
          }
    \item Some Item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem.

However, the tcolorbox in this environment refuses to break between pages. Any idea of how to achieve breakable tcolorbox in the above environment?