# Itemize in tcolorbox

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox, itemize

My MWE is

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable] 
Hello! $x^2$
\begin{itemize}
\item Ok
\item Hi
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and I basically want the enumerating label to be outside of the box. I have tried embedding a minipage inside the tcolorbox environment but that seems to remove the breakable property and the number gets placed to the middle left of the tcolorbox instead of the top left.

It seems that this happens with nested enumerate also, it doesn't need to be itemize. My current scrappy fix was  \leavevmode  \vspace{-\baselineskip} before \begin{tcolorbox} but that doesn't seem to play well when I have multiple tcolorboxes one after the other (there seems to be a large space between them that I cannot bridge).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: something like this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477830/tcolorbox-as-an-item-in-list-environment -- you could also include a hand sketch of the desired output